# Detect image failure generation

Tags: node.js, image-processing

I use a renderer server that delivers images in base64 and when there is a failure during the rendering, it responds with a... 200 status code and a white image. 
I would like to detect a white image to generate an error to the client.
What should I do?
Thank you!

Comment: compute average of image, if it is equal to 255 then image is totally white.

Comment: Thank you. The bigger the image is, the longer the script will be, right? Don't you think the calculation of the file size is a good approach?

Comment: obviously, loop will run more times for bigger image. File size might be a good approach, this info might be present in file header and if file is compressed then white image data might be represented by three bytes.